# XTermjs - How to resize XTerm terminal to match the exact dimensions of the window?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, xtermjs

I have the following code that is part of a React class component:

```
render () {
    return (
        <div id = 'remote-console'>
        </div>
    )
}
```

and my application currently opens a new browser window with a console interface. I was wondering how I would be able to make this window resizable (and have the xterm console fit to the new dimensions). I currently use the FitAddon addon for xterm, but I'm not sure how to get the console to resize to the size of the current window (including the height)

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.console = new Terminal()
    this.fitAddon = new FitAddon()
    this.console.loadAddon(this.fitAddon)
    this.console.open(document.getElementById('remote-console'))
    this.fitAddon.fit()
    window.onresize = function () {
        this.fitAddon.fit()
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you using to connect to real terminal, e.g., powershell, cmd etc? you watch for the `onResize` event from `Terminal` and in that event you can send to the backebd the new rows/cols to set to the real terminal. If you are using something like `node-pty` to connect to real terminal, just pass the values sent from `onResize` to `resize` from `spawn` (from `node-pty`) module. check out this https://github.com/princjef/xterm-electron-sample/blob/2ec9bbd3dd492fec4f5f5677deb04edb069ca17a/src/renderer/index.ts#L36